# Resetting admin password with Sitecore 9.1.1 and Identity Server after SHA512 change

Tags: security, login

I'm going through the security hardening steps on a new, local instance of Sitecore 9.1.1 with identity server. I made the SHA512 change in the Sitecore web.config, and I ran the database script to reset the password/salt appropriately:

```
UPDATE aspnet_Membership
SET Password = 'K8N8GUW8UiNT2mPdjvuBDH+QmvA3R61M9buVvCwFHwtDjpMzTxs34lg0uQ0azCITqh6FkUZlX4kM72lsAyuyXQ==', 
PasswordSalt = 'p5B6HOWKt0ctMZaSNXTlfw=='
FROM aspnet_Membership m INNER JOIN aspnet_Users u ON m.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE u.UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
```

However, I still cannot log into the CM. I'm guessing something else needs changing on the identity server side, but I don't see any references to SHA512 in that code. There was a reference online regarding an appsettings.json file for identity service in relation to Commerce, but not XP0, and that file doesn't exist that I can see.

Comment: Similar question to https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17980/1278 which has no answer at time of writing.

Comment: From what I can see, it should be possible to clone and modify https://github.com/sma73648/identityserver-contrib-membership/blob/develop/src/IdentityServer4.Contrib.Membership/MembershipPasswordHasher.cs and just overwrite the IdentityServer4.Contrib.Membership.dll. But to me this isn't a good solution as it's way out of support. I'd recommend opening a Sitecore support ticket and request a patch for this.

Comment: I opened a ticket, thanks!

Comment: This issue has been registered as a bug with public reference number 302092. There is  a hotfix available for Sitecore Identity Server 2.0.0 which supports SHA512. Contact Sitecore Support for the hotfix.